# Hook form alter not firing on a custom form that does exist

Tags: theming, forms, javascript

I have a hook form alter function that is not recognizing or firing on a form that clearly does exist on the page. And i’ve tested this function against the Drupal built in form with the id of ‘search_block_form’.
In my template.php file i have this code.

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
if($form_id == 'search_block_form'){

    echo '<script>alert("whatup?");</script>'; /* for testing purposes */
    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.accordion');   

    $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('enter burp search terms...');
    }

if($form_id == 'views-exposed-form-browse-albums-page') {
    echo '<script>alert("whatup beeatch?");</script>'; /* for testing purposes */
    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.accordion');
}
```

}

As a test first IF statement alters the default Drupal search whose id is  ‘search_block_form’. This part does run and is working.

The second IF statement tests for my custom views form but does not run at all. The form does clearly exist (see attached). I’m stumped at this point and don’t know what to do next. Why is the second IF statement not running?

[image]

Comment: Use underscores instead of dashes.

Answer (score 2):

Before Drupal 8, the form ID is also the name of the PHP function that builds the form itself (or an ID contained in the array Drupal gets from a `hook_forms()` implementation).
As such, it can only contains those characters a PHP function name can contain. Underscores are allowed, but not so dashes; dashes are used in HTML. The correct form ID is the one with underscores.